# ASP.net core RegularException attribute - multiple conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-core

I have two regex that should be matched:

```
"^[a-z0-9\\!@\\$\\^&\\-\\+%\\=_\\(\\)\\{\\}\\<\\>'\";\\:/\\.,~`\\|\\\\]+$"
```

and

```
".*(g[o0]+gle).*"
```

The first one accept any alpha numeric character (with few more extras). Like `helloworld123`. The second one should reject any string that contain the word "google" (in diffrent forms - like: `gooo0gle`).

Allowed:

```
hello
helloworld
helloworld123
```

Disallowed:

```
hellogoogle
google
...
```

I want to use the `RegularExpression` to match this string. Thought about something like:

```
[RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9\\!@\\$\\^&\\-\\+%\\=_\\(\\)\\{\\}\\<\\>'\";\\:/\\.,~`\\|\\\\]+$|.*(g[o0]+gle).*"]
```

But it's not working since the second part (`.*(g[o0]+gle).*`) should be NOT.

How to do it right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your second regex by placing it in a **[negative look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** and use the first regex as character set and combine both to get following regex that you can use,

```
^(?!.*g[o0]+gle)[-a-z0-9!@$^&+%=_(){}<>'";:\/.,~`|]+$
```

Here, this `(?!.*g[o0]+gle)` negative look ahead will reject any strings that contains `google` or any variation as supported by your regex, and this character set `[-a-z0-9!@$^&+%=_(){}<>'";:\/.,~`|]+` will match one or more characters allowed by it.

Also, you don't need to escape most special characters while they are in character set, hence I have unescaped most of them except `/` and also always place the hyphen `-` either as the very first character or very last character in the character set, else depending upon the regex dialects, you may see weird behavior.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YQHd35/1)**